# How to occupy entire editorss area with a view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How to occupy entire editorss area with a view?

I can do this by

```
layout.addView(ID, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 1.0f, "org.eclipse.ui.editorss");
```

but it appears temporary (view stops occupying full area at some drag).

I know it is prohibited by the doc.

Also I can't do this from `plugin.xml`. If I set `1.0` then the value is ignored and assumed `0.5`.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

Interactively I can put editor into view area. Can I do opposite, i.e. put view onto editor area?

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Ok I found a way to occupy entire editor area by a view interactively: one should drag to the left of the area title so that short green mark appears:

[image]

This way any view can be put anywhere.

Hence, the question is reasonable and persists: how to do that programmatically?

**UPDATE 3**

This works in `Juno` and `Kepler` and probably above, but not works in `Indigo` and probably below.

**UPDATE 4**

And the dragging also works in written plugins. I.e. I can place my view to entire area manually, but I don't know how to do this programmtically.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the Eclipse 3.x APIs, the Eclipse 4.x (e4) application model APIs will let you put anything anywhere (which is what the UI code is using).

Comment: Can we hook `e4` from within `3.x` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Make editor area visibility to false as shown below in your `Perspective` class.

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IPageLayout;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveFactory;

public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    @Override
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this way I will be unable to leave "empty" region between views, right? And I wish to be able to.

Comment: Yes.Why?. Also note that view toolbars are local to view BUT ALL editors toolbar will be contributed to main toolbar thus you can identify view and editor visually.

Comment: Because I wrote my editor as `ViewPart` and I wish it behave visually as an editor.

Comment: Why you are using ViewPart to create Editor. You can use EditorPart. Basically Editors will follow Edit, Modify, Save cycle but views were not. Views are designed to reflect the information in editor and/or in some other view. Is there any strong reason to created editors using `ViewPart` instead of `EditorPart`?

Comment: I have already switched to EditorPart, but the question is sensible.